# How to make a class-wide ID number

Tags: swift, class-variables

Perhaps I am simply reading old material, but I can't see a way to do something seemingly very simple.

I have a class called `Robot`, each instance of which needs a unique `id`. The `id` is simply an `Int` that should be 1,2,3... The normal solution would be to have a class var `MaxId` that you increment in the `init()` and then assign that to the instance's `id`.

Swift (4?) does not have class vars, but does have computed properties at the class level. However, I am a bit mystified about how one might use this to do a `MaxId`. Am I missing something blindingly obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables are essentially class variables.  Try this in a playground:

```
class Numbered {
    static var serial: Int = 1
    let myID: Int

    init() {
        myID = Numbered.serial
        Numbered.serial = Numbered.serial + 1
    }

}

print(Numbered().myID)
print(Numbered().myID)
```

Comment: Ahhh. So the very many questions about the difference between static and class vars do not *clear* state this! Thanks!

Comment: Do note that `serial` will reset to `1` each time your app runs.

Answer (score 2):

> a unique id. The id is simply an Int that should be 1,2,3.

You can certainly use a static property and increment it, but note that 
those are two different requirements. If all you *really* want is a unique id, there is no need for the “least available integer” approach. Just use the built-in [UUID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid) struct and move on.